# Is possible to fire a Canon 430 EX II (off camera) using a Canon 100D without trigger?

Tags: canon, off-camera-flash

Is possible to fire a Canon 430 EX II (off camera) using a Canon 100D without a separate trigger?

Comment: Also see http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43363/4892

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't possible just using the camera alone.

You will need to buy additional hardware, or upgrade to a different camera like a 700D, 750D, or 760D which have a built-in master flash mode.

Answer (score 1):

The first resource you should look at for a great introduction to flash photography is strobist.com's Lighting 101. In particular, there's a post there called [Synching Your Flash](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/03/lighting-101-pc-cords-and-pocket.html) that shows you how to trigger your off-camera flash using just a 1/8" audio patch cord and a pair of adapters. (See also [Understanding Your Flash](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/03/lighting-101-start-here.html).)