# Please confirm whether the Canon 430EX can be used as off camera flash with the Canon EOS 1300d

Tags: canon, off-camera-flash

Please confirm whether the Canon 430EX can be used as off camera flash with the Canon EOS 1300d. I have been searching online and asked different Facebook groups (which non of them answered to my question) but till now it is still an answered question. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you mean by "off camera flash"? Possibilities include 1) not physically mounted to the camera but connected by a bit of wire 2) optical triggers 3) radio triggers 4) something else.

Comment: This question might help [Do Canon 430EXII speedlite flash units have an optical slave function?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43363/do-canon-430exii-speedlite-flash-units-have-an-optical-slave-function)

Comment: Which 430EX? The current version (430EX III-RT) can be radio-controlled (in addition to the optical control of the previous versions) so this opens your options...

Comment: @xenoid The 430EX is the 430 EX. The 430EX II and 430EX III-RT are not the 430EX. If the OP meant 430EX II or 430EX III-RT when naming the 430EX, that needs to be corrected. But as the question now stands, it's specifically asking about the 430EX, not the 430EX II or 430EX III-RT.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Canon 430EX can not operate as an off camera flash with your EOS 1300D, unless you add some extra equipment.

More advanced cameras like the 600D, 700D, 80D, 90D, etc. can use the built in, pop-up flash to trigger the 430EX, but your 1300D can not.

You will need to buy a master flash like the 580EX II or 600EX.

Answer (score 2):

Since the pop-up flash on your 1300D can not be used as a Master Flash in Canon's E-TTL optical wireless flash system, you can not fire an off camera 430EX or 430EX II using your EOS 1300D without additional hardware.

To use a 430EX or 430EX II off camera with your 1300D, you have several options:

- Use an on-camera TTL Master, such as a Canon 580EX II, 90EX, or third party flash that is capable of being used as a Canon E-TTL Master Flash
- Use a Canon ST-E2 near-infrared flash Controller (if you can still find one) or third party clone (if you can find one)
- Use a Canon compatible off camera shoe cord, such as the Canon OC-E3 or clones which are available in a wide variety of lengths
- Use a set of radio triggers that are compatible with Canon E-TTL if you want to do more more than tell the flash when to fire
- Use a set of cheap manual radio triggers to fire the flash, which must be set in manual mode using the flash's own control panel

With the first two options, the Master Flash or Controller would be placed on the camera's hot shoe and the built in optical receiver on the 480EX or 480EX II would respond to the output of the Master Flash or Controller.

With the last two options, the transmitter would be placed on your camera's hot shoe and the receiver's hot shoe would be connected to the flash's hot foot.

Answer (score 1):

Not without additional gear.

Canon reserves a flash "master" for the built-in pop-up flash for the ###D/T#i series of digital Rebels (T3i and later) and higher-end camera bodies. The SL/T### and ####D/T# line bodies do not have this capability.

And Canon's EX-designated and EL series flashes can all be "slaves" in the system, do not have simple optical slave capability that works with any flash burst (e.g., S1/S2 "dumb" optical slave modes).

To use a 430EX/430EX II/430EX III-RT off-camera with a 1300D, you need to use an appropriate "smart" optical "master" unit on the camera hotshoe (ST-E2, 550EX, 580EX, 580EX II, any of the RT or EL models).  Or, an appropriate radio transmitter (RT-compatible for the built-in receiver on the 430EX III-RT; e.g. ST-E3-RT) and matching radio receiver on the foot of the flash (if, say, you go with 3rd-party triggers).

See also: [What features should one look for when selecting a flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722/what-features-should-one-look-for-when-selecting-a-flash)